# GraphQL Cursor Based Pagination with Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, graphql, apollo, relay, apollo-server

I've been learning GraphQL for a little while. I understood concept of simple queries and mutations. Now I'm trying to implement a Relay style cursor based pagination. I can create the results like  edges, totalCount, hasNextPage, hasPreviousPage etc. But I feel like I'm querying the database too much. I mean one "find" for edges, one for totalCount (countDocuments() in mongoose), and one for hasNextPage and hasPreviousPage each.

I have a structure that if the client not asking for the totalCount, that query doesn't execute for example. Thanks to field resolvers.

I've tried things like keeping the limit "first + 1", so if the client asks for 5 records and the query finds 6, then "hasNextPage" is true etc.

But I'm still trying to find a solid example. I want to know the best practices but nearly all of the examples has **mock data**. No real database, just some object arrays. They just slice it and return.

How can I find an example or learn the best practices. I've been reading Facebook's Paging Specification. I've even looked into source codes of mongoose relay pagination packages but they feel like a mess when you're trying to learn something.

I'll be grateful for any good example.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[The Road to GraphQL](https://roadtoreact.com/) by Robin Wieruch is a free open source book resource that has examples of setting up pagination server and client side.  I highly recommend it to learn and understand pagination, it's the resource I'm using in my first Graphql project.

Comment: I've read some of his tutorials and I think he is great! I didn't realize that he has written that much of a source at the beginning, but now I am following his works.
Thanks btw!